# Python Sphinx WARNING: Definition list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent

Tags: python, python-sphinx

My doc is like this:

```
    def segments(self, start_time=1, end_time=9223372036854775806, offset=0, size=20):
        """Get segments of the model

        :parameter
            offset: - optional int
            size: - optional int
            start_time: - optional string，Segments 
            end_time: - optional string，Segments 
        :return: Segments Object
        """
```

When I make html, it turns out:

```
 WARNING: Definition list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
```

I have no idea where I should add a blank line?

I searched SO, but can not find any similar case as mine.

Comment: I'd guess before the `:return:` line, that's where your list of `:parameter`s ends.

Comment: Ohh, you're right, could you tell me what this format called?(like google format or numpy?) on other doc, I use format like `:param name: xxx`  there is no blank line needed before `:return:`

Comment: When you repeat `:param[eter]` on each line you're not making a definition list, so you there's nothing to end with a blank line.

Comment: OK, I see. could you leave an answer, I'll accept, thanks.

Comment: The format you are trying to use is neither Google nor Numpy style. It is the default format that Sphinx works with unless you enable the napoleon extension. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/extensions/napoleon.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Question was already answered by *jonrsharpe* in a comment, but i want to complete it here.

You are using the default Sphinx Style ["reStructuredText"](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html)

You have to add ":parameter" on every line:

```
    """Get segments of the model
    
    :parameter offset: optional int
    :parameter size: optional int
    :parameter start_time: optional string，Segments 
    :parameter end_time: optional string，Segments 
    :return: Segments Object
    """
```

If you had created a dedicated definition list, then you would need an empty line after the last definition. In this case, you can do it, but don't always have to.

Comment: For future me, remove blank spaces above the first `param` and ensure that `return` is written as `:return:`. The `return` issue may not be as important as the space issue. End of future notice.

Comment: I assume I'm not the only one who curses whenever I run into the crazy limitations and runic syntax of RST/Sphinx.  For example if you do something as innocent as indent a line and have a hyphen in it, 
it squawks.  It pays lots of attention to (invisible) white space. The official documentation MENTIONS definition lists under glossary but does NOT have an entry explaining the syntax.

Almost any MD is less elegant, but far easier to get right.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message but the issue was slightly different. I had a multiline parameter description.

```
    """Get segments of the model
    
    :parameter offset: optional int and this was very long 
    description of the parameter. Which runs over
    multiple lines.
    :return: Segments Object
    """
```

To solve the issue I had to add indentation for each row in the description. The final code looks like this:

```
    """Get segments of the model
    
    :parameter offset: optional int and this was a very long 
        description of the parameter. Which runs over
        multiple lines.
    :return: Segments Object
    """
```

Another confusing aspect was that error did not reference the real problem but rather the file's first function.